# Connect timeout from external clients?

Tags: nginx, amazon-aws, node-js

I had a MEAN site hosted on DigitalOcean, and now I moved it to an EC2 micro instance. I imported the database, set up PM2, copied all files and everything, and set up Nginx as a reverse proxy. No biggie.

When I "curl localhost", the site loads perfectly. But I can't connect to it from anywhere except localhost. For example, running "curl " on the old VPS gives a "connection timed out" error. And when I try to access the site in Chrome, it loads until a timeout error as well.

As you can imagine, I am confused. The following is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  ssl on;

  server_name  my-domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

}
```

Is there something I am missing here? Thanks again, just very new to AWS, and a bit confused.

Comment: And how long have you waited for DNS changes to take effect?

Comment: Haven't changed the DNS yet, I'm trying to connect via the actual IP, just to make sure things are working.

Comment: Then you can't use `server_name www.my-domain.com  my-domain.com;` in your virtual host, since your not telling it to use an IP address.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/243109/cant-access-nginx-server-from-ip

Comment: Did that resolve the issue or not?

Comment: No, it actually wasn't. I assumed it was the UFW firewall, and that wasn't it either. It turns out AWS has its own additional firewall that blocked the connection. Thanks, though.

Comment: If you know the answer, be sure to leave it and mark it as accepted, as this will help other users in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

On an EC2 instance, ensure the following:

- Nginx is on, and whatever server_name you're using will allow you to access it.
- If your server has UFW on, then make sure incoming TCP connections are allowed (on ports 80 and 443)
- Lastly, go to "edit inbound rules" in your instance's security group, and allow incoming connections via 80 and 443.

Good to go!